# some noob wsdl questions

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

```
<xsd:element name="loginResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="loginReturn" type="tns:test"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:complexType name="test">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="tx" type="xsd:int"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="result" type="xsd:int"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="name_space" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I just want to ask why is the type `tns:test` used? How can I get the tx, result, namespace values in complextype name="test", because that's the response should I get based on the api they given to me.

Comment: `tns:` most likely refers to the target namespace (i.e., the XML namespace for that service, and the namespace where the complex type `test` is defined). Are you using JAXB? If not, why not?

Answer (score 0):

**`tns` is the target namespace prefix**, which should be defined at the top of your WSDL or XSD file (which includes `test`).

You didn't wrote how you do access the values, but I assume that your code is working in a different namespace, so that `test` cannot be indentified. Most likely there is a method which allows you to get values by element name **and namespace**. Note that in that case, the namespace isn't `tns` but rather the URL which is defined at top of source file.

If you're not familiar with namespaces: *Each XML element is associated with a namespace, like a class in Java is part of a package. In XML there is no `import` statement, so you have to name an element by name and namespace. To keep the files readable you can define namespace prefixes (probably as an abbreviation).*